# научился печатать - правильно ли Грамота объяснила?

Tags: сказуемые

Грамоте задали вопрос: какую функцию выполняет "печатать" в предложении “я научился печатать на клавиатуре вслепую”? Дополнения или составного глагольного сказуемого?

> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> ***Если следовать "букве закона", то есть формальным правилам, то научился в Вашем предложении - часть составного глагольного сказуемого с модальным значением.***

Далее идет объяснение:

Если следовать "букве закона", то есть формальным правилам, то научился в Вашем предложении - часть составного глагольного сказуемого с модальным значением. Вот почему:
[Е. И. Литневская Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников](http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm#31202)

***Приинфинитивная часть составного глагольного*** сказуемого выражает грамматическое значение сказуемого, а также дополнительную характеристику действия — указание на его начало, середину или конец (фазисное значение) или возможность, желательность, степень обычности и другие характеристики, описывающие отношение субъекта действия к этому действию (модальное значение).
***Фазисное значение выражается глаголами стать, начать (начинать), приняться (приниматься), продолжить (продолжать), перестать (переставать), прекратить (прекращать) и некоторыми другими (чаще всего это синонимы к приведенным словам, характерные для разговорного стиля речи):***
Я начал / продолжил / закончил читать эту книгу.

***Модальное значение может выражаться***
1) глаголами ***уметь, мочь, хотеть, желать, стараться, намереваться, осмелиться, отказаться, думать, предпочитать, привыкнуть, любить, ненавидеть, остерегаться*** и Т. п.
2) глаголом-связкой быть (в наст. времени в нулевой форме) + краткими прилагательными ***рад, готов, обязан, должен, намерен, способен,*** а также наречиями и существительными с модальным значением:

> Я был готов / не прочь / в состоянии подождать.
>
> Не являются составными глагольными сказуемые, выраженные:
>   1) ***составной формой будущего времени глагола несовершенного вида в изъявительном наклонении***: Я завтра буду работать;
>   2) ***сочетанием простого глагольного сказуемого с инфинитивом, занимающим в предложении позицию дополнения в случае разных субъектов действия у спрягаемой формы глагола и инфинитива:*** Все просили ее спеть (все просили, а спеть должна она);
>   3) ***сочетанием простого глагольного сказуемого с инфинитивом, который в предложении является обстоятельством цели***: Он вышел на улицу погулять.

Нетрудно заметить, что во всех этих случаях спрягаемая форма глагола, стоящая перед инфинитивом, не имеет ни фазисного, ни модального значения.

Конец цитаты.

Но тогда как раз и выходит, что "научился" - простое глагольное сказуемое, а "печатать" - дополнение.

Тем более буквально на аналогичный вопрос Грамота ответила:

Вопрос № 273909
в предложениях типа Я УЧУСЬ ЧИТАТЬ глагол ЧИТАТЬ является сказуемым или дополнением? Почему?

> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Это дополнение. Инфинитив (читать) может быть частью сказуемого, только если глагол в личной форме имеет модальное или фазовое значение: хочу (могу) читать, начал читать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я учусь(чему?) читать-дополнение.

Я научился (что делать?) - сост. глаг.сказуемое.

Нужно учитывать лексическое значение.Если учусь - овладеваю какими-либо знаниями, то научился, выучился - конец этого процесса, итог =окончил учиться. Так что фазисное значение содержится изначально в глаголе как окончание действия.

Формальное разграничение происходит в плоскости "субъектный инфинитив(действие подлежащего, глагольн. сказуемое) / объектный инфинитив(действие другого действ. лица, дополнение)". У нас субъектный инфинитив, значит, сост.глагольное сказуемое.

Если бы не было рядом инфинитива,глагол "научился" был бы самостоятельным простым глаг. сказуемым со значением "освоил знания и умения"-научился стойкости, выдержанности..., а "выучился" со значением "получил образование, специальность", а вот рядом с инфинитивом утрачивает самостоятельность, фазисное значение превалирует.

Comment: Людмила, а "я учусь печатать" - это какое сказуемое? И  мне кажется сомнительным фазисное, а не  модальное значение глагола "научился". Вы не могли бы рекомендовать разбор подобного варианта в каких-либо источниках?

Comment: "У нас субъектный инфинитив, значит, сост.глагольное сказуемое". У Валгиной на этот счет другое мнение. Думаю, что принципиальное различие не в инфинитиве, а в значении (обязательно фазовом или модальном) вспомогательного глагола.

Comment: Я учусь (чему?) печатать-дополнение. Я научился печатать = закончил учиться печатать. Здесь фазовое и модальное значения совмещены. А дополнение всегда объектное, субъектным не бывает,почему ж этот факт не может быть принципиальным различием?

Comment: Вообще забавно, что для простейшего предложения предлагаются разные решения, Вы не находите?  Грамота вот дает разные ответы. А как в школе разбирают дети эти предложения "Я учусь читать. Я научился читать". Тоже рассуждают о совмещении фазовых и модальных значений?  Но так любой глагол совершенного вида можно назвать фазовым.  А по поводу субъектного инфинитива посмотрите, пожалуйста, мое дополнение к ответу.

Answer (score 2):

Я учусь печатать на машинке. Это дополнение (чему?). Я научился печатать на машинке. Разницы в формальной грамматике никакой, тоже дополнение.

Но по смыслу это означает:  я умею печатать на машинке. Составное глагольное сказуемое, вспомогательный глагол с модальным значением.

Отсюда ответ: формально "печатать" - это дополнение, но семантически "научился печатать" близко  к составному глагольному сказуемому.

**НАУЧИТЬСЯ,  св. чему или с инф.** Приобрести навыки, умение делать, понимать, чувствовать и т.п. что-л. Н. плаванию, чтению. Н. ходить на лыжах, печатать на пишущей машинке. Н. вышивать, печь пироги, управлять машиной. Н. понимать людей. Н. видеть прекрасное, отличать плохое от хорошего.

КАКИЕ БЫВАЮТ ДОПОЛНЕНИЯ

Валгина Н.С. Современный русский язык. Синтаксис. Высшая школа, 2003 год

**Дополнения, выраженные инфинитивом, обозначат действие как объект, на которое направлено другое действие.  В роли дополнения может выступать субъектный и объектный инфинитив**.

Например: Они уговорились (о чем?) встретиться завтра. Это субъектный инфинитив в роли дополнения.

Таким образом, объектный инфинитив - это всегда дополнение, **а субъектный инфинитив может быть дополнением или входит в состав СГС.**